# Reading tab delimited files in f#

Tags: parsing, file-io, f#, csv

I'm new to F# and don't have a lot of experience with functional languages. I need to select the values in a couple of columns of a tab delimited file. I've found how to read lines of a text file into sequences, but sequences don't seem to work like arrays and I can't figure out how to select a specific value from them. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the [CSV type provider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html) to do this. It supports tab-delimited files too (see the "Custom separators and tab-separated files" section on that page).

To use the type provider, you'll need a sample (which could also be your actual input file). Then you can tell the type provider to infer a type based on your sample. If you have `tsv` extension, it automatically treats it as tab-separated, but you can also specify separators explicitly:

```
type MyFormat = CsvProvider<"C:/sample.tsv", Separators="\t">
```

Then you can use the inferred type to read your data:

```
let data = MyFormat.Load("C:/mydata.tsv")
for row in data.Rows do
  printfn "%s" row.YourColumn
```

Comment: The files I'm trying to read have three rows at the end with only 2 columns, whereas the rest of my rows have 22 columns. I don't need those last three, is there a way I can have it ignore those columns?

Comment: Add  IgnoreErrors to type MyFormat = CsvProvider<"C:/sample.tsv", Separators="\t" IgnoreErrors=true>.
According to [Doc](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html) setting
 IgnoreErrors static parameter to true so that lines with incorrect number of elements are automatically skipped.